# shell script functions arguments/parameters

Tags: function, shell, sh

i'm playing around with basic shell scripts and would like to know how to do the following if possible

i have created a basic script with a function and i want to call it when i type the main command with variables like first name and surname

> source ./test.sh; talk $John $Smith

```
  function talk($firstName, $lastName)
{
        echo "hi! ${firstName} ${lastName}"
}
```

I cant seem to get it to work,not sure where im going wrong, i've tried reading up but getting confused

Comment: As an aside -- the `function` keyword is not part of POSIX-standard function declaration syntax; it's a ksh extension picked up by bash (not guaranteed to be supported with `/bin/sh`, and not necessarily even a good idea to use in shells that *do* support it). See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should not be necessary.

```
talk()
{
   echo "hi! $1 $1"
}
```

defines the function.
After a source you can invoke it with

```
talk Hans Peter
```

In sh variables are not declared with a prefix $, but accessed that way:

```
a=5
echo $a
```